# SOP (Same Origin Policy) and CDN SVG XSS

Tags: xss, same-origin-policy, svg

If an SVG file with an XSS payload is hosted on say cdn.example.com and is loaded as a display picture on say mainprod.com, can the XSS payload within the SVG file access and steal cookies from mainprod.com despite the Same-Origin Policy (SOP) being in place or would SOP prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mainprod.com` is loading the image from `cdn.example.com` via `<embed>`, like this:

```
<embed src="https://cdn.example.com/whatever.svg" width="300" height="200">
```

then, the JavaScript code within the SVG will actually execute, but in the security context of `cdn.example.com`. Therefore, no attack is possible here. The script will not be able to access the contents/cookies of `mainprod.com` due to same-origin policy.

If `mainprod.com` is loading the image from `cdn.example.com` via `<img>`, like this:

```
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/whatever.svg" width="300" height="200">
```

then, no JavaScript code within the SVG will execute at all. All the JavaScript code within the SVG will be ignored by the browser and only the image will be rendered. Same origin policy will not play any role here, as there is no JavaScript executing at all.

So in the above scenarios, no attack is possible. The only possible attack scenario which could lead to XSS is if `mainprod.com` fetches the contents from `https://cdn.example.com/whatever.svg` server-side and writes the response directly into the `mainprod.com` HTML document. However, this scenario is highly unlikely.

Comment: To test this I used [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0ftrh8os/1/) code on site a and on site B I used [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6x35emsh/) svg XSS payload. Now what I am seeing is when I visit site A there are no XSS pop-up's however, when from site A I right click on the image and open it in new tab the cookies from site A are displayed in site B when the XSS is triggered. Is it supposed to happen?

Comment: Hey @mateleco, I'm curious about my situation. Is there any possibility of exceptions to this rule? I had a scenario where I hosted an HTML file and another SVG file with to XSS payload on the same IP address, but with different ports. Specifically, site A, which contained the HTML fetching an SVG from site B, was hosted on 192.168.1.1:8080, while site B, where the SVG was located, was hosted on 192.168.1.1:8000.

Comment: I guess it's because SOP only works on domains and not IP addresses directly.

Comment: No, it's not because domain vs IP address. It's because cookies don't follow *same origin* rules. Cookies are shared across ports. See here: [are cookies port-specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific/16328399#16328399)

Comment: Cookies can also be shared across subdomains. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie). Basically, if you are in example.com and execute `document.cookie="test=123;domain=example.com;path=/"` you will be able to see this cookie from all subdomains of example.com (e.g. asd.example.com, foo.example.com etc.) and even sub-sub-domains (foo.bar.example.com).

Comment: Cookies are also shared between http/https unless you specify the `Secure` option. For example, if the `Secure` option is not present, you will be able to see a cookie both from `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`

Comment: As you may have noticed, cookies follow far less strict rules than same-origin rules. Same origin rules require equal protocol, hostname and port. See more about [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#definition_of_an_origin).

Comment: The Same Origin Policy (SOP) comes into play especially for things like making AJAX or Fetch requests, accessing the contents of an iframe or window etc., but not for cookies. Cookies follow very different rules, as I explained in the previous messages.